# Listify (wp job manager) edit listing bug

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Wp job manager / Listify champs.

Im trying to develop a website for the first time using wp-job-manager and listify theme.

**i didnt touched at all** the registration from and for some reason, im getting the error below when im accessing the **registration/editing form logged in**

if im not logged in its working fine.

what can be the problem?

```
Warning: include(/home/XXXX_username/public_html/w/XXXX.com/wp-   
content/themes/listify/inc/integrations/wp-job-manager/templates/form-fields/-
field.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/eyala246/public_html/w/XXXX.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-job-
manager/wp-job-manager-template.php on line 26

Warning: include(): Failed opening 
'/home/XXXX_username/public_html/w/XXXX.com/wp-
content/themes/listify/inc/integrations/wp-job-manager/templates/form-
fields/-field.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php56/pear') in 
/home/XXXX_username/public_html/w/XXXX.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-job-
manager/wp-job-manager-template.php on line 26
```